# Porting Ndis5 driver to Ndis6

Tags: c++, windows, driver, ndis

I'm porting a driver from Windows XP to Windows 10 (big leap!). I am following the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570025(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to port the driver but some things are missing.
I need to know what replaces:

1. TransferDataCompleteHandler
2. ResetCompleteHandler
3. ReceiveHandler
4. ReceiveCompleteHandler
5. StatusCompleteHandler

attributes in the NDIS_PROTOCOL_DRIVER_CHARACTERISTICS structure.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you porting a miniport driver or a protocol driver? The MSDN link points to the miniport porting guide, whereas the functions listed are all from `NDIS_PROTOCOL_CHARACTERISTICS`.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link, its a IM driver